# Imported StencilJS to Vue - fonts don't work

Tags: css, vue.js, fonts, web-component, stenciljs

I just created my first web components package with StencilJS. Using `@stencil/sass` I made global styles which will apply to whole page. Additionally I made font-faces in Stencil, but It don't load in my VueCLI project, where I imported my web components.

Font-faces code:

```
@font-face
  font-family: 'Uniform Condensed'
  src: url('assets/fonts/files/uniform/uniform_cyr_condensed-web.woff2') format('woff2')
  src: url('assets/fonts/files/uniform/uniform_cyr_condensed-web.woff') format('woff')
  font-weight: 400
  font-style: normal
  font-display: swap

@font-face
  font-family: 'Uniform Extra Condensed'
  src: url('assets/fonts/files/uniform/uniform_cyr_extra_condensed-web.woff2') format('woff2')
  src: url('assets/fonts/files/uniform/uniform_cyr_extra_condensed-web.woff') format('woff')
  font-weight: 400
  font-style: normal
  font-display: swap

@font-face
  font-family: 'Uniform Extra Condensed'
  src: url('assets/fonts/files/uniform/uniform_cyr_extra_condensed_medium-web.woff2') format('woff2')
  src: url('assets/fonts/files/uniform/uniform_cyr_extra_condensed_medium-web.woff') format('woff')
  font-weight: 500
  font-style: normal
  font-display: swap

@font-face
  font-family: 'Noe Display'
  src: url('assets/fonts/files/noe/Noe_Display_Bold-web.woff') format('woff')
  font-weight: 400
  font-style: normal
  font-display: swap
```

I know the problem is with links. If I will put `assets` folder from my Stencil package into `public` It works, but I want fonts to load automatically after import.